# Free MobileGIS like ArcPAD

Tags: open-source-gis, gps

I'm looking for open-source program like ArcPAD. 
I have read all questions and answers, but i find nothing. I need the program for PDA (Dell axim x51v + GPS modul) and I want mapping points (trees or buildings), lines (roads) and polygons (forests).Then I want to do a simple web-mapping project. Thanks for sharing your knowledge.
Regards Brtko

Answer (score 5):

There is a program called gvSIG Moblie https://gvsig.org/web/projects/gvsig-mobile/tour/image-gallery

Answer (score 4):

MapTools (Mobile)
http://mobile.maptools.org/index.phtml?page=home.html

Full list of Open Source Mobile GIS Applications:

http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Mobile_Solutions#Existing_Projects

Comment: Hey Mapperz, when you go to MapTools site, it says that there are no downloads available at this time.

Answer (score 2):

Can I ask the question "if you want something like ArcPad, why not use ArcPad?" There are two clear parts to your project, the data collection and then the web mapping part.

I guess you are not going to find something as detailed as ArcPad, because it has a 10 year history of development. I often wonder why people don't just pay for the product as many people don't take into consideration the cost of their own time as part of the cost in the project. How much time are you spending researching other software applications, testing them and the potential ongoing costs of maintenance for custom applications. It also depends on your skill set personally or in your office that you can pool from. If you have .Net people or Java then maybe look for something that suits them to help solve the problem. Where if you have no support around you and you want to have custom applications then maybe that sways your decision too. Finally, which software is going to fit best into your organisation? What devices are available? Many more questions could be asked.

Sorry if this muddies the waters but I feel these are all good questions to ask yourself before just wanting to go open source.

Cheers,

Gareth

Comment: well, one reason to search for alternatives is that Arcpad doesn't support wms and wfs or tiled services wich is a quite natural way to get map-data when you are on the run.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at QMAP.

http://nathanw.net/2012/09/10/announcing-qmap/

I don't have personal experience with it, but when I asked the same question you did in LinkedIn forums this was the resounding open-source / cheaper answer.

To Gareth's point if you need something and have the cash flow to buy it ArcPad is a very good option. Especially now with version 10. That said I have been using it since version 6 and for a complex application. I made it work but I did ask whether there was a better way.